# How to use Container to access parameters on a custom Exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I have been struggling a bit to understand how can I make use of the `Container` that gives me access to the parameters located at `config/parameters.yml`.

The problem in my hands is I created some custom `Exceptions` and I created a library that slacks me every time one of those exceptions is triggered. For that, I need to send the `container` to the Logger in order to be able to pull those through within the library.

But I am failing to be able to grab a hold on the `container`. I have an idea it needs to be injected and that I could achieve such in the `config/services.yml` but I am failing to understand how.

So far this is what I have come to achieve:

**My Custom Exception Parent**

Because all exceptions extend from the parent, they will all trigger the `Logger`. And it is at this point I need the `container` to exist:

```
abstract class CriticalLogAlertException extends \RuntimeException
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct ($message = "", $code = 0, Throwable $previous = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

        Log::critical(
                      $this->message, 
                      [], 
                      AbstractCredentialsFactory::YAML_TYPE,
                     'PARAMETERS CONTAINER ACCESS NEEDS TO BE ADDED HERE'
                    );
    }

    abstract public function generateMessage($message) : string;
}
```

What I though was on creating on this class a method `setContainer()` that I could use in my `config/services.yml`:

```
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container - $container;
}
```

So at this point I could create a `property` in the abstract class and use that to pass it to the `library` as it would be already available at `class execution`. Though I am not too certain this is **achievable** or **correct**;

**My config/services.yml**

Below is the code I added to my services container:

```
 ExceptionContainer:
      class: AppBundle\Exception\CriticalLogAlertException
      calls:
          - [ setContainer,[ @service_container ] ]
```

Could someone help me understanding if it something I am missing or misunderstanding in order to set it available?

**NOTE:** If there is anything else required to better understand my problem, please let me know so I can update my question :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is how are you creating the instances of those exceptions? Do you have any factory? Or do you just creating them directly with the “new” operator?

Comment: Are you using the Symfony framework or just a few components?  It is a bit strange that you are trying to add this sort of stuff to the exceptions themselves.  Look in the docs to see how to setup a custom exception handler.

Comment: I am instantiating them when they are caught with `try...catch` by doing `throw new MyCustomException`. @DavidKmenta I am not making use of a factory for the exception types though you lift a fair point and I should! @Cerad I am using the symfony3 framework. Though I might have to adjust my Exception, my problem resides on the **container** to have access to the parameters at **parameters.yml**. Thank you both for your help as well!

Comment: Exceptions should not have access to the container.  Again, read up on how Symfony deals with exceptions.  It's not Laravel and "facades" are not part of the process.

Comment: Just use a factory and inject a logger into it (not whole container), than pass the injected logger into each exception ;)

Comment: Was to avoid spreading the Log through the program. That is why I was trying to find the solution through this. This way I could have a Log in the Parent Exception but to use the library created I need to pass the Container. Using a factory though will still present me with the same problem. Need a container to use the log library

Comment: Or to put it another way, exceptions should not be doing logging.  That is the job of exception listeners.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for the clarification! Will look into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, this took me a while but I had to dive deeper in order to understand, which meant to go through some fights and research before being able to start understanding it a bit better.

Was left for a while even though I got it working a while back, but for those wondering the same and new to the process let me share a bit :)

Because I was instantiating the exceptions with `throw new` meant I had direct access to the `__construct` method. This meant, if my exception was expecting a `ContainerInterface` I had to provide one.

Now, two case scenarious could work with this.

**1. Injection**

With Injection I can autowire the requirements either by using an available service (which we can check with below command);

```
php bin/console debug:autowiring
```

Or, if injecting a **custom** class, I needed to specify where, which and what it provides at `services.yml`

An possible example of what I am refering to add to `services.yml` can be seen below:

```
TestException:
        class: AppBundle\Exception\TerminationAmlkyc
        arguments: ['@service_container']
        public: true
```

**2. Instantiation**

In my case, I either transferred the `ContainerInterface` whenever I needed it for a new class or was able to Instanciated as I referenced above.

Because my origin was through a `ContainerAwareCommand` I could make use of `$this->getContainer()` to retrieve it and then pass it to the exceptions whenever needed.

```
throw new TestException($this->getContainer())
```